# Jquery not selector returning unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a custom jquery selector called `deletable`

With this selector I get all divs that I need to get. 
But I have some of these divs containing elements that I don't want so I want to exclude them.

Example :

```
:deletable returns 3 divs, two of those divs have input elements. I want to get the one without input elements
```

I tried this (and many other variants):

```
$(':deletable:not(:deletable:contains(input))')
```

Not working, I still get all three divs.

I'm using this inside `.on()` function like this :

```
$(document).on('click', ':deletable:not(:deletable:contains(input))' ...)
```

So I don't know how to use `.filter()` function with on (that might be the key).

How do I use `:not` properly in my case

Comment: And if that doesn't work, you could put 'if($(this).contains('input')) return;' inside the click handler, although Lix's method would be preferable

Comment: @Lix the `:contains` selector: "Select all elements that contain the specified **text**."

Comment: @gve - [True true true...](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: may be `:has`? like this: `$(document).on('click', ':deletable:not(:has(input))' ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(':deletable').not($(':deletable:has(input)'));
```

**[Illustrative] DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/A3yGQ/